# нарисовать равнобедренный треугольник в обратную сторону (основание должно лежать справа). использовать вложенные циклы

Tags: c++, циклы

У меня есть часть кода, который рисует прямоугольник с основанием слева, нужно переделать так, чтобы основание было справа, а вершина треугольника слева(то есть перевернуть его). Мой код:

```
int w, h;
for (int i = 1; i < w; i++) {

        if (i <= w / 2)
        {
            h = i;
        }
        else if (i > w / 2)
        {
            h = w - i;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да просто добавьте перед звездочками вывод пробелов... Вместо

```
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

напишите

```
    for (int j = 0; j < w/2-h; j++) cout << " ";
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) cout << "*";
    cout << endl;
```